# Is it possible to use Rest-API to subscribe tokens on my app-server which does not use Admin SDK?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am writing a server in a language (Rust) that hasn't an official driver from the Firebase team. I am doing Rest-API calls to Firebase Cloud Messaging which also works fine.

I am interested in subscribing clients to topics in my server. I don't see Rest-API as a supported way of adding/removing subscribtions from topics server-side: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/manage-topics.

> The Firebase Admin SDK allows you to perform basic topic management
> tasks from the server side.

Is Rest-API supported, or not at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

subscribing to FCM through restapi is not possible: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/manage-topics only admin sdk makes this possible

Comment: Sadly, those SDK languages does not support by most shared hosting which uses PHP, perl and no CLI access to install Node.js. FCM admin is not shared hosting friendly.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue where FCM document does not support REST API for managing topics. However, there are multiple languages that [provide admin SDKs for FCM such as Python and Go](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/manage-topics). I used Python with print in requests.py to find the HTTP request which looks like this:

To subscribe to a topic:

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer ya29.c.b0Aaekm1KT19VSl43n25GJKc7j" 
-H "access_token_auth: true" 
-d '{ 
"to": "/topics/your_topic_name", 
"registration_tokens": [ 
    "YOUR_REGISTRATION_TOKEN_1", 
    "YOUR_REGISTRATION_TOKEN_n" ] 
}' https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1:batchAdd
```

To unsubscribe from a topic:

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer ya29.c.b0Aaekm1KT19VSl43n25GJKc7j" 
-H "access_token_auth: true" 
-d '{ 
"to": "/topics/your_topic_name", 
"registration_tokens": [ 
    "YOUR_REGISTRATION_TOKEN_1", 
    "YOUR_REGISTRATION_TOKEN_n" ] 
}' https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1:batchRemove
```

where the token is get through : https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server

And don't forget the header : `"access_token_auth: true"`, which is required.